# Submit/load/submitted/editsave data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form ***data_form.php*** submitting data to a ***write_files.php*** . here are generated the ***myFile.xml*** and ***myFile.html*** files.

The ***myFile.html*** is actually an optical copy of form ***data_form.php*** but with fields filled by values read from ***myFile.html*** or ***myFile.xml***).

There is also generated a ***list.html*** of links to saved html files.
I need another form ***edit_data.php*** (actually the same as ***"data_form.php"***) where the data from linked HTML files would be read and I sould them edit and save under new names,

e.g.: ***myNewFile.xml*** and ***myNewFile.html***.
Reading and editing the XML files works fine with `$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);`.

But, is there similar way how to handle the html files?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But it is more than a university to understand all the comments on this page.
In my index.php, there is a list of created files and a link to data_form. The submits 30 fields to write_files.php, where both XML and HTML files are created. The user only sees the HTML result. The XML is for another purpose there. What I am looking for, is the solution to open desired file from the index.php in HTML form and be able to edit the edited files in new named XML and HTML again.

Comment: I have forgotten to mention that in the index.php, there is a field, where the user desids under what name shall his info be saved. This name is then used also as a link both to XML and HTML version.